# People who are financially secure without having to work, why do you work?

Tags: work

People who are financially secure without having to work, why do you work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a student but my uncle is in the financial position (and age, 63) to retire but he chooses to work. He is the kind of guy who has built businesses all of his life and has told me he will continue to do so until he is physically unable. I asked him something similar not long ago and this is what he told me:

- He enjoys his work and finds it rewarding. It's no longer about the money.
- Working keeps his mind and body sharp. He enjoys the challenges
  and problem solving. It allows him keep active and stay relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you enjoy what your doing and/or if what you are doing is your natural 'calling' you are not really 'working'.  Think about it.  What you do for the majority of your daily waking, non-eating, non-commuting, non-bathroom, hours defines who you are.  It is part of your identity.  It gives you satisfaction.  It is part of your mission in life and you would do it for free.

Many of us cannot choose to live our calling because we are not financially independent.  We have to accept the jobs that the system provides in our locality.  We cannot afford to wait for the job we want and/or we don't have the resources to start our own business in said profession.  Being financially secure gives you that freedom to choose.